# RenPy: Python .format translate

Tags: python, renpy

I'm creating a translation for a visual novel, and I can't translate the text with string formatting, does anyone know how to do this?

Code to translate:

`$ gil_likes = "Teasing {0}, Basketball".format(Main)`

The translation must be something like this:

`old "Teasing Walter, Basketball" new "Дразнить Уолтера, Баскетбол"`

I try to replace {0} with a specific name, but then the translation works only for that specific name, the problem is that the player can enter any name

Comment: More context would help, but does [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) have an answer to your question?

Comment: Hi, sorry for long respond. In renpy code, i have these lines:
$ gil_likes = "Teasing {0}, Basketball".format(Main)
Where {0} is name of main character, but in translation folder, line: 
old "Teasing {0}, Basketball".format(Main)
don't work, i need to do something with string format. I find that 
old "Teasing %s, Basketball" % "Walter"
will work, but instead of "Walter" I need a variable, and I don't know how to do it, sorry for bad English